# JOIN with priorised criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

I have to match each record in TABLE1 with at most 1 record in TABLE2.
There is a better way to match (CODE equality) and a poor one (in case of no CODE equality, let's sort by CODE and match by index).

Let's suppose as a first approximation that the code doing this might look like this :

```
SELECT
TABLE1.CODE AS CODE1,
TABLE2.CODE AS CODE2
FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CODE) INDEX, CODE FROM TABLE1) T1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CODE) INDEX, CODE FROM TABLE2) T2
ON
(T1.CODE=T2.CODE) --CODE equality
OR
(T1.INDEX=T2.INDEX) --CODE equality
```

Let's consider these tables :

```
 TABLE1   TABLE2
+------+ +------+
| CODE | | CODE |
+------+ +------+
| AAA  | | BBB  |
| BBB  | | CCC  |
| CCC  | | DDD  |
+------+ +------+
```

The result will be :

```
CODE1 CODE2
----- -----
AAA   BBB    -> matched because of INDEX equality
BBB   BBB    -> matched because of CODE equality
BBB   CCC    -> matched because of INDEX equality
CCC   CCC    -> matched because of CODE equality
CCC   DDD    -> matched because of INDEX equality
```

Here comes the difficulty : I'd like to express the notion that despite there are 2 conditions of matching which are not mutually exclusive, the first one must be preferred to the second if possible, and the second must be evaluated **if and only if** the first one fails.

The wanted result being :

```
CODE1 CODE2
----- -----
AAA   DDD    -> matched because of INDEX equality between the cast-off records not able to match better
                (corrected from the previous version where AAA was said to match expectedly with BBB)
BBB   BBB    -> matched thanks to CODE equality, no need to match on INDEX
CCC   CCC    -> matched thanks to CODE equality, no need to match on INDEX
```

And of course I would preferably obtain this behavior all-in-one-query to avoid a several-steps script, given that :

- you can feel free to propose a totally different query : the one above was just there to illustrate the general idea, but it's clear it doesn't fit the needs. So, no need to try to preserve its structure.
- I don't really care about performance compared to the wish to perform an all-in-one-query matching. If subqueries are needed, let's go ! ;-)

Eager to read your suggestions ! :-)

**EDIT :**

I made a strong error in my OP which is now corrected and deeply changes what can be considered as an accurate answer. The expected results were not right. My most humble apologies. :-(

The idea is : match as much as you can on CODE equality, then consider only those which are left behind by this first matching algorithm to match them by INDEX. That's why AAA which was incorrectly expected to INDEX-match with BBB (which already CODE-matches with another BBB), must in fact INDEX-match with another non CODE-matching item, in that case DDD.

Comment: Should your second subquery be against Table2 and not Table1?

Comment: Sorry, yes of course. I corrected the OP.

Comment: @Ssithra: Do the two fields `CODE` have a UNIQUE constraint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.
I post the answer in case it could be of any interest for somebody out there.
It can be adjusted depending on the final needs but the idea is there (I slightly changed the names of the fields/constants : it's more close to the real life names and helped me to find the solution, it would have been too theorical otherwise).

```
declare @uc table(cod_uc varchar(3))
declare @cnt table(cod_cnt varchar(3))

insert into @uc values('a')
insert into @uc values('b')
insert into @uc values('c')
insert into @cnt values('b')
insert into @cnt values('c')
insert into @cnt values('d')
insert into @cnt values('e')

;with codematchings(cod_uc,cod_cnt)
as
(a
    select uc.cod_uc, cnt.cod_cnt
    from 
    @uc uc full outer join @cnt cnt on uc.cod_uc=cnt.cod_cnt
),
orders(cod_uc,order_uc,cod_cnt,order_cnt)
as
(
    select cod_uc,row_number() over(order by isnull(cod_uc,'zzzz')) order_uc, cod_cnt,row_number() over(order by isnull(cod_cnt,'zzzz')) order_cnt from codematchings where cod_uc is null or cod_cnt is null
)
select codematchings.*,
case
when codematchings.cod_uc is null then orders2.cod_uc
when codematchings.cod_cnt is null then orders2.cod_cnt
else codematchings.cod_uc
end matched_with
from codematchings
left outer join orders orders1
on codematchings.cod_uc is null and orders1.cod_cnt=codematchings.cod_cnt or codematchings.cod_cnt is null and orders1.cod_uc=codematchings.cod_uc
left outer join orders orders2
on codematchings.cod_uc is null and orders2.order_uc=orders1.order_cnt or codematchings.cod_cnt is null and orders2.order_cnt=orders1.order_uc
```

Result :

```
cod_uc cod_cnt matched_with
------ ------- ------------
A      NULL    D
B      B       B
C      C       C
NULL   D       A
NULL   E       NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your test data and expected results, this gives the correct results.

```
;WITH T1 (row_id, code) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code) AS row_id, code FROM My_Table_1),
     T2 (row_id, code) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code) AS row_id, code FROM My_Table_2)
SELECT
    T1.code,
    COALESCE(T2.code, T3.code)
FROM
    T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T2.code = T1.code
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 AS T3 ON T2.row_id IS NULL AND T3.row_id = T1.row_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried on Oracle but the idea is here :

```
with t1 as (select 1 id,'AAA' col from dual union all
            select 2,   'BBB'     from dual union all
            select 3,   'CCC'     from dual ),
     t2 as (select 1 id,'BBB' col from dual union all
            select 2,   'CCC'     from dual union all
            select 3,   'DDD'     from dual )
---
SELECT t1.col col1, t2.col col2
  FROM t1, t2
 WHERE (t1.id = t2.id OR t1.col = t2.col)
   AND (t2.id = 1 OR t1.col = t2.col)
```

results :

```
COL1 COL2
---  ---
AAA  BBB
BBB  BBB
CCC  CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial Data:

```
; WITH 

  T1 (CODE) AS
  ( SELECT 'AAA' CODE UNION
    SELECT 'BBB'      UNION 
    SELECT 'CCC'
  )
, T2 (CODE) AS
  ( SELECT 'BBB' CODE UNION 
    SELECT 'CCC'      UNION 
    SELECT 'DDD' 
  )
```

Help tables:

```
 , FULLT (code1, code2) AS
   ( SELECT T1.CODE AS code1
          , T2.CODE AS code2
     FROM T1
       FULL OUTER JOIN T2
         ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE 
   )
 , INNERT (code1, code2) AS
   ( SELECT code1
          , code2
     FROM FULLT
     WHERE code1 = code2 
   )
 , LEFTT (code1, rn) AS
   ( SELECT code1
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY code1) AS rn
     FROM FULLT
     WHERE code2 IS NULL
   )
 , RIGHTT (code2, rn) AS
   ( SELECT code2
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY code2) AS rn
     FROM FULLT
     WHERE code1 IS NULL
   )
```

Final query:

```
   SELECT code1             
        , code2
   FROM INNERT 

 UNION ALL

   SELECT code1
        , code2
   FROM LEFTT
     JOIN RIGHTT
       ON LEFTT.rn = RIGHTT.rn 

 ORDER BY code1
        , code2
```